# Redirection without template?

Tags: php, templates, containers, redirect, httpresponse

Why in my view i'm redirect in new page without template ?

This is my view/Profiles/tmpl/borrowings.php

```
<?php 
$config = [
'view'                => 'Borrowings',
'filter_order'        => 'borrow_from',
'filter_order_Dir'    => 'DESC',
'layout'              => 'profile',
'tmpl'                => 'component',
'task'                => 'browse',
'limit'               => '0',
'nglibrary_member_id' => $member->getId(),
'render_toolbar'      => false
];

FOF30\Container\Container::getInstance('com_nglibrary', [
'tempInstance' => true,
'input' => $config
 ])->dispatcher->dispatch();
 ?>
```

and that is my View/Borrowings/tmpl/form.profile.xml

```
<form
type="browse"
show_header="1"
show_filters="1"
show_pagination="1"
norows_placeholder="COM_NGLIBRARY_COMMON_NORECORDS"
<headerset>
    <header name="title" type="Searchable" sortable="false" />
    <header name="authors" type="Field" sortable="false" />
    <header name="library" type="Field" sortable="false" />
    <header name="borrow_from" type="Field" sortable="false" />
    <header name="borrow_to" type="Field" sortable="false" />
</headerset>
<fieldset name="items">
    <field name="title" type="Text" />
    <field name="author" type="Text" />
    <field name="library" type="Text"/>
    <field name="borrow_from" format="%d %m %Y" type="Calendar"/>
    <field name="borrow_to" format="%d %m %Y" type="Calendar"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

When I filter the list or make a search in type="searchable" the result appear in new page without template. Please can somebody tell me why?